# Как присваивать ноепределенное количество файлов к модели Django

Tags: python, django

У меня еслт две модели `Task_users` и `Task`.Я хочу передовать модели `Task_users` файлы(программы на компеляцию) и точное количество `Тасков` я не знаю , как мне присвоить несколько файлов к `Task_users`, при этом не преписывая к `Task_users` новое поле файла??

```
from django.db import models
    class Task_users(models.Model):
        task_username = models.CharField('имя пользователя' max_length=50)
        task_user_class = models.CharField('класс пользователя' max_length=50)
        task_user_password = models.CharField('пароль пользователя' , max_length=50)
        task_user_file=models.FileField('файл пользователя')

        def __str__(self):
            return self.task_username

class Task(models.Model):
    Task_user = models.ForeignKey(Task_user , on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    task_title = models.CharField('название таска' , max_length=50)
    task_text = models.TextField('текст статьи')
    task_input = models.CharField('мпример ввода таска' , max_length=50)
    task_output = models.CharField('мпример вывода таска', max_length=50)
    task_ids = models.CharField('id таска' , max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.task_title
```

Comment: Сложно понять, но, судя по всему, нужно создать новую таблицу для `File`, и связать `Task_users` с ней через FK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Необходимо создать ещё одну модель, например `TaskFile`, которую по `ForeignKey` связать с `Task`. Ну и соответственно кроме ForeignKey добавить поле типа `FileField`.